# Why are empty and non empty TikZ matrix cells not equally placed?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I wanted to draw an almost empty `matrix of nodes` with `TikZ` similar to the left most one below. All nodes would have same size (through `minimum width` and `minimum height`) and no separation between columns and rows. But when I include a text which needs two lines I obtain the central matrix and, if the text just needs one line the right most one. I don't know what's wrong. Do you? I'm using CVS version of `TikZ`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
proces/.style={draw, minimum height=15mm, minimum width=2cm, outer sep=0pt, text width=1.5cm, align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & \\
 & \\
};

\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & OOO OOO \\
 & \\
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
\matrix (B) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & A \\
 & \\
};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Weigh anchor and hoist sail for TikZland.  Seriously, try `nodes={anchor=center}`.  The style `matrix of nodes` automatically sets the anchor to `base` and I suspect (only suspect) that this is the cause of the shifts.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Verified. Godspeed...

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Perfect! Thank you! Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What's happened here is that the `matrix of nodes` has quietly set `anchor=base` on each of your matrix subnodes.  The problem with this is that when the node has text in it then the `base` anchor is not in the same place as the `center` anchor.  So your nodes are lining up so that their `base`s are in a line but this means that their `center`s (and thus their boundary) are not.

The simplest solution is to put `nodes={anchor=center}`, or you could add it to the `proces` style, after the `matrix of nodes` to revert this change.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
  process base/.style={
    draw,
    minimum height=15mm,
    minimum width=2cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    text width=1.5cm,
    align=center
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  proces/.style={
    process base,
  }
]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & \\
 & \\
};

\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\matrix (B) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & OOO OOO \\
 & \\
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
\matrix (C) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & A \\
 & \\
};
\end{scope}

\foreach \lbl in {A,B,C} {

\draw[line width=3mm,green] (\lbl-1-1.base) -- (\lbl-1-2.base);
\draw[ultra thick,red] (\lbl-1-1.center) -- (\lbl-1-2.center);

}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
  proces/.style={
    process base,
    anchor=center,
  }
]


\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & \\
 & \\
};

\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\matrix (B) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & OOO OOO \\
 & \\
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
\matrix (C) [matrix of nodes,nodes=proces,nodes in empty cells] {
 & A \\
 & \\
};
\end{scope}


\foreach \lbl in {A,B,C} {

\draw[line width=3mm,green] (\lbl-1-1.base) -- (\lbl-1-2.base);
\draw[ultra thick,red] (\lbl-1-1.center) -- (\lbl-1-2.center);

}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned anchors]