# tikz matrix not distributed evenly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

How can I make the box distribute evenly?
code as below:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\lw{1pt} %define linewidth here
\tikzset{box/.style={draw,rotate=90,inner sep=0pt,line width=\lw,
    minimum width=2.2cm,minimum height=2.2cm,text width=1.6cm}}
\matrix (M1) [matrix of nodes,draw,inner sep=2pt,
        row 1/.style={align=right},
        row 5/.style={align=left},
        row sep=-\lw,column sep=-\lw,
        nodes={box},nodes in empty cells]{
 & PORCH 1st &  & DOOR & \\
 &  &  &  & \\
 &  &  &  & \\
 &  &  &  & \\
 & BSMT & GARAGE & PORCH 2nd & \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now the output seems ugly:
[image]

Comment: Does `inner sep=2pt` do anything?

Answer (score 3):

Add `anchor=center` to your `box/.style`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\lw{1pt} %define linewidth here
\tikzset{box/.style={draw,rotate=90,inner sep=0pt,line width=\lw,
    minimum width=2.2cm,minimum height=2.2cm,text width=1.6cm,anchor=center}}
\matrix (M1) [matrix of nodes,draw,inner sep=2pt,
        row 1/.style={align=right},
        row 5/.style={align=left},
        row sep=-\lw,column sep=-\lw,
        nodes={box},nodes in empty cells]{
 & PORCH 1st &  & DOOR & \\
 &  &  &  & \\
 &  &  &  & \\
 &  &  &  & \\
 & BSMT & GARAGE & PORCH 2nd & \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: matrix]

Comment: Great, it works now. but why the default anchor so "unstable", it should align the same style but my original output is so "random" distribute.

Comment: The manual states on page 227: "When you place a node at some coordinate, the node is centered on this coordinate by default." So it could be a bug.

Comment: @Benjamin: It's not a bug, by design `matrix of  nodes` sets `anchor=base` which is different in empty and non empty nodes. Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78964/why-are-empty-and-non-empty-tikz-matrix-cells-not-equally-placed

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks. I now also found it in the manual. I have missed that this is a duplicate. Should I just keep my answer here or delete it? I could not find a clear answer on Meta.

Comment: @Benjamin  Your answer is correct and useful for people who arrives here. So, why to delete it?