# tikz matrix cells not aligned correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am trying to use matrix to draw cells, but the example code not aligned correctly from left to right. and some white space between the up/down cells also!

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\def\adot{\tikz{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0] {}}}
\def\bdot{\tikz{
    \node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0] (x) {};
    \node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0,below=1pt of x] (y) {}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
    box1/.style={fill={rgb,255:red,3; green,220; blue,128},minimum width=2em,minimum height=2em},
    ]
\matrix (n) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0,column sep=0,
    nodes={box1}] {
0 & \bdot \\
1 & \adot \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong with my code?

[image]

Comment: Nesting TikZ pictures is deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two issues. First of all, as @egreg mentioned, it is deprecated to nest `tikzpictures`, but this was actually not the reason for the problem. Rather, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79031/121799), there is also an issue with the node anchors, which @BambOo's answer solves by adding the phantoms. As long as the matrix stays as simple as in your example, this trick may work. However, if the matrix is meant to get extended, I'd like to argue that the following solution is cleaner.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
    box1/.style={fill={rgb,255:red,3; green,220; blue,128},minimum
    width=2em,minimum height=2em,anchor=center}, % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79031/121799
    remember picture] %<-added
\matrix (n) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0,column sep=0,
    nodes={box1},nodes in empty cells] {%<-added nodes in empty cells
0 &  \\
1 &  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\draw[fill=black] (n-1-2.center) circle (2.5pt);}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\draw[fill=black] ([yshift=2pt]n-2-2.center) circle (1pt);
\draw[fill=black] ([yshift=-2pt]n-2-2.center) circle (1pt);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It does not have nested `tikzpicture`s, nor phantoms.

Comment: Nice! But you switched the position of the dot and the double dot. xD

Answer (score 4):

a simple solution, maybe you liked:

- simple matrix of math nodes,
- definition of nodes in matrix options
- for "dot" and >"colon" are used math expression used `\bullet`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (n) [matrix of math nodes,
             column sep=0pt,
             row sep=0pt,
             nodes={fill=green,
                    minimum size=2.2em,
                    anchor=center
                    }
             ]
{
0 & \bullet\atop\bullet \\
1 & \bullet             \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

**addendum**: with boldface colon:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{bm} % <--- added

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (n) [matrix of math nodes,
             column sep=0pt,
             row sep=0pt,
             nodes={fill=green,
                    minimum size=2em, % <--- changed/reduced
                    anchor=center
                    }
             ]
{
0 & \bm{:}          \\ % <--- changed
1 & \bullet         \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You like the matrices, the tables, apparently ahahah. :-) I upvote you.

Comment: Good idea! How can I adjust the distance of \atop? I wish to shrink the distance between the two dot but "node distance" option doesn't work.

Comment: @lucky1928, for `\atop` i need to search site if here is something about this. meanwhile i provide solution without `\atop`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `\vphantom{0}` before your `\adot` and `\bdot` gives

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

add anchor=center to box.
If draw border, add -\pgflinewidth to remove duplicate grids.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\def\adot{\tikz{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0] {}}}
\def\bdot{\tikz{
    \node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0] (x) {};
    \node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0,below=1pt of x] (y) {}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
    box1/.style={draw,fill=gray!20,minimum width=2em,minimum height=2em,
    anchor=center}, %<-- add anchor
    ]
\matrix (n) [matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep = -\pgflinewidth, %<-- remove duplicate grid line
    nodes={box1}] {
0 & \bdot \\
1 & \adot \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]