# Different arrow shapes using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

[image]

I am trying to reproduce this state transition diagram in `LaTeX`. This is the first paper I've written using `LaTeX` so my knowledge is limited. I am struggling to find a way to get the arrows to bend in the rectangular way shown in the image and to also control the height of how far the arrow goes from the nodes. The code I currently have is below:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{block1}=[rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{block2}=[rectangle, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=0.6cm, text centered, draw=black]
%\tikzstyle{doublearrow}=[thick,<->,>=stealth,<=stealth]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (X) [block2] {$X$};
\node (Y1) [block2, left of=X,xshift=-1cm] {$Y_1$};
\node (Z1) [block2, left of=Y1,xshift=-1cm] {$Z_1$};
\node (Y2) [block2, right of=X,xshift=1cm] {$Y_2$};
\node (Z2) [block2, right of=Y2,xshift=1cm] {$Z_2$};

\draw [arrow,above] (X) -- node{{\scriptsize $\beta_1XY_1$}} (Y1);
\draw [arrow] (Y1) -- node {{\scriptsize $\gamma_1Y_1$}} (Z1);
\draw [arrow] (Z1) |- node{{\scriptsize $\delta_1\beta_1Y_1Z_1$}} (Y1);
\draw [arrow] (Z1) |- node {{\scriptsize $\lambda_1Z_1$}} (X);
\draw [arrow,above] (X) -- node[anchor=west] {{\scriptsize $\beta_2XY_2$}} (Y2);
\draw [arrow] (Y2) -- node{{\scriptsize $\gamma_2Y_2$}} (Z2);
\draw [arrow] (Z2) |- node{{\scriptsize $\delta_2\beta_2Y_2Z_2$}} (Y2);
\draw [arrow] (Z2) |- node{{\scriptsize $\lambda_2Z_2$}} (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a TikZ-Matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usepackage{pgf} % loaded by tikz
% \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows} % not used
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, rounded corners, 
]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={anchor=center},
column sep=5em, row sep=2em, 
]{
        &            &      &            &              \\
Z_1     &  Y_1       &  X   &  Y_2       &  Z_2         \\
        &            &      &            &              \\
%1  &  2 & 3 & 4 & 5             \\
};

% Annotations
\draw[->] (m-2-1) -- (m-1-1.center)  -- (m-1-2.center) node[midway, above]{$a b c$} -- (m-2-2);  
\draw[->] (m-2-4) -- (m-1-4.center)  -- (m-1-5.center)  node[midway, above]{$c d e$} -- (m-2-5);  

\draw[->] (m-2-1) -- (m-3-1.center)  -- (m-3-3.center) node[midway, above]{$f g h$} -- (m-2-3);  
\draw[] (m-2-3) -- (m-3-3.center)  -- (m-3-5.center) node[midway, above]{$i j k$} -- (m-2-5);  

\foreach[evaluate={\Col=int(\col+1)}] \col/\text in {1/A,2/B} 
\draw[<-] (m-2-\col) -- (m-2-\Col) node[midway, above]{$\text$};  

\foreach[evaluate={\Col=int(\col+1)}] \col/\text in {3/C,4/D} 
\draw[->] (m-2-\col) -- (m-2-\Col) node[midway, above]{$\text$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `matrix of nodes` and `matrix of math nodes` fixes node's alignment to `base`. This is the reason of not horizontal arrows between $X$ and $Y_1$ or $Y_2$. I suggest to add `nodes={anchor=center}` to avoid this problem. More details in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78964/1952

Comment: OK......................

Comment: Just what I needed thank you so much.