# tikz: execute at begin box breaks matrix align

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I'd like to insert automatically some text in some nodes inserted in a matrix, so I'm using `execute at begin node`. But unfortunately, the nodes are shifted up and not aligned anymore:

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
  box/.style={
    draw,
    minimum height=10mm,
    minimum width=3cm,
    fill=green!50,
  },
  boxA/.style={
    box,
    execute at begin node={A},
  },
  emptyBox/.style={box},
  ]%
  \matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
  {
    |[boxA]| & |[emptyBox]| \\
    |[boxA]| & |[emptyBox]| \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

-- EDIT --
Oh, I just realized it was not just because of `execute at begin node`, but any text makes it shift... What's wrong?

Comment: If you want to know why this happens, take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78964/1952

Answer (score 1):

Actually we just need to set `anchor=center` to the box (or specify manually the `text depth`/`text height`, thanks hrnz):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
  box/.style={
    draw,
    anchor=center,
    minimum height=10mm,
    minimum width=3cm,
    fill=green!50,
  },
  boxA/.style={
    box,
    execute at begin node={A},
  },
  emptyBox/.style={box},
  ]%
  \matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
  {
    |[boxA]| & |[emptyBox]| \\
    |[boxA]| & |[emptyBox]| \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem you solve yourself in your answer (+1), so only some remarks:

- Probably you have some reason why you use option `execute at begin node` instead insert desired cell's content directly in matrix cells. Later leads to simpler code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes, 
         nodes in empty cells,  % new                    
         nodes={draw, fill=green!50, anchor=center, % new
                minimum width=30mm, minimum height=10mm}, % new
         row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
{
    A   &   \\
    A   &   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- In case the same contents of cells are long, it may make sense to use a combination of your approach using `execute at begin node` and the matrix's cells style from the previous example. For example as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
cA/.style={execute at begin node={$E=mc^2$}}, % modified your approach
                        ]
\matrix [matrix of nodes, 
         nodes in empty cells,
         nodes={draw, fill=green!50, anchor=center,
                minimum width=30mm, minimum height=10mm},
         row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
{
    |[cA]|    &   \\
    |[cA]|    &   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]