# Table in LaTeX using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have tried to do a rather complicated table using `Tikz` in two different ways, none of which gives a perfect result. In the example that I have attached you can see the result of both. I don't understand why, in the first case the smaller boxes doesn't close, and in the second why there in a gap between rows.

I would be grateful for any advice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.8\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%row 1/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
%column 4/.style={nodes={fill=pink}},
%row 4 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=blue}}
]

\matrix(m) [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,nodes={minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,outer sep=0pt}]
{
      &       &      &    &     &   &   &   &   &  &  &  &  &\\
       &    10 &      &     30 &      4 &    &  50&      8 &      &   &    12&   &   &  \\
       &   &   &   &   &   & &   &   &  &  &  &  & 125  \\
      &   &    &  10  &   &   & 30 &   &   & &  &  &  & \\
       & 4  &   &  40 & -4  &   &  &  -4 &   &  35 & 10 &  &  & \\
      &   &  &  &      &  &  &   &   &  &  &  &  & 55 \\
       &    &    &  10 &   &   & &   &   & 5 &  &  &  &  \\
       & 6  &   &    & 4  &   & &  8 &   &  &  -8 &  & 20 &  \\
       &   &    &   &   &    &  &   &   &  &  &  &  & 30 \\
       &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  &  &  &  & \\
       &   & 90  &   &   & $\le 60$  &   &   & $\le 65$  &  &  & 20 &  & \\
};


\draw (m-2-2.north west) rectangle (m-10-13.south east);

% Lineas horizontales
\draw (m-4-2.south west) -- (m-4-13.south east);
\draw (m-7-2.south west) -- (m-7-13.south east);

% Lineas verticales
\draw (m-2-4.north east) -- (m-10-4.south east);
\draw (m-2-7.north east) -- (m-10-7.south east);
\draw (m-2-10.north east) -- (m-10-10.south east);





\draw (m-4-4.north west) rectangle (m-4-4.south east);

\draw (m-2-4.south west) -- (m-2-4.south east);
\draw (m-2-3.north east) -- (m-2-3.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-3-4.south west) -- (m-3-4.south east);
\draw (m-4-3.north east) -- (m-4-3.south east);

%limite superior
\draw (m-2-7.south west) -- (m-2-7.south east);
\draw (m-2-6.north east) -- (m-2-6.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-3-7.south west) -- (m-3-7.south east);
\draw (m-4-6.north east) -- (m-4-6.south east);

% Segunda fila
% Casilla 2-1
%limite superior
\draw (m-5-4.south west) -- (m-5-4.south east);
\draw (m-5-3.north east) -- (m-5-3.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-6-4.south west) -- (m-6-4.south east);
\draw (m-7-3.north east) -- (m-7-3.south east);

% Casilla 2-3
%limite superior
\draw (m-5-10.south west) -- (m-5-10.south east);
\draw (m-5-9.north east) -- (m-5-9.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-6-10.south west) -- (m-6-10.south east);
\draw (m-7-9.north east) -- (m-7-9.south east);

% Tercera fila
% Casilla 3-4
%limite superior
\draw (m-8-13.south west) -- (m-8-13.south east);
\draw (m-8-12.north east) -- (m-8-12.south east);


% Para dibujar cuadrados
%\node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(m-2-2)(m-4-4),inner sep = -5pt] {};



%\node[label=above right:$20$] at (m-2-3){33};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}



\begin{center}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.8\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%row 1/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
%column 4/.style={nodes={fill=pink}},
%row 4 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=blue}}
]

\matrix(m) [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,nodes={minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,outer sep=0pt}]
{
      &       &      &    &     &   &   &   &   &  &  &  &  &\\
       &    10 &      &     30 &      4 &    &  50&      8 &      &   &    12&   &   &  \\
       &   &   &   &   &   & &   &   &  &  &  &  & 125  \\
      &   &    &  10  &   &   & 30 &   &   & &  &  &  & \\
       & 4  &   &  40 & -4  &   &  &  -4 &   &  35 & 10 &  &  & \\
      &   &  &  &      &  &  &   &   &  &  &  &  & 55 \\
       &    &    &  10 &   &   & &   &   & 5 &  &  &  &  \\
       & 6  &   &    & 4  &   & &  8 &   &  &  -8 &  & 20 &  \\
       &   &    &   &   &    &  &   &   &  &  &  &  & 30 \\
       &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  &  &  &  & \\
       &   & 90  &   &   & $\le 60$  &   &   & $\le 65$  &  &  & 20 &  & \\
};


\draw (m-2-2.north west) rectangle (m-10-13.south east);

% Lineas horizontales
\draw (m-4-2.south west) -- (m-4-13.south east);
\draw (m-7-2.south west) -- (m-7-13.south east);

% Lineas verticales
\draw (m-2-4.north east) -- (m-10-4.south east);
\draw (m-2-7.north east) -- (m-10-7.south east);
\draw (m-2-10.north east) -- (m-10-10.south east);

% Primera fila
%limite superior
\node[draw=blue,fit=(m-2-4)(m-2-4),inner sep = 0pt] {};
\node[draw=blue,fit=(m-4-4)(m-4-4),inner sep = 0pt] {};
\node[draw=blue,fit=(m-2-2)(m-4-4),inner sep = 0pt] {};


%limite superior
\draw (m-2-7.south west) -- (m-2-7.south east);
\draw (m-2-6.north east) -- (m-2-6.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-3-7.south west) -- (m-3-7.south east);
\draw (m-4-6.north east) -- (m-4-6.south east);

% Segunda fila
% Casilla 2-1
%limite superior
\draw (m-5-4.south west) -- (m-5-4.south east);
\draw (m-5-3.north east) -- (m-5-3.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-6-4.south west) -- (m-6-4.south east);
\draw (m-7-3.north east) -- (m-7-3.south east);

% Casilla 2-3
%limite superior
\draw (m-5-10.south west) -- (m-5-10.south east);
\draw (m-5-9.north east) -- (m-5-9.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-6-10.south west) -- (m-6-10.south east);
\draw (m-7-9.north east) -- (m-7-9.south east);

% Tercera fila
% Casilla 3-4
%limite superior
\draw (m-8-13.south west) -- (m-8-13.south east);
\draw (m-8-12.north east) -- (m-8-12.south east);


% Para dibujar cuadrados
%\node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(m-2-2)(m-4-4),inner sep = -5pt] {};



%\node[label=above right:$20$] at (m-2-3){33};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To prevent everything jumping all around, you can specify `text height` and `text width` for the nodes.

Comment: This is basically the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78964/why-are-empty-and-non-empty-tikz-matrix-cells-not-equally-placed --- you can see it if you add `draw=red` to your node definition. Adding `anchor=center` will probably fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full example demonstrating what @hpekristiansen suggests. Note that

- `matrix of nodes` is replaced by `matrix of math nodes`, so that every node in `\matrix` is no in math mode.
- `minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm` is replaced by more compact `minimum size=1cm`.
- `text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex` is added, using the same height and depth value as in the [pgf manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), section 5.1. That section also provides explanation about why the options `text height/text depth` is required to align node text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.8\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%row 1/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
%column 4/.style={nodes={fill=pink}},
%row 4 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=blue}}
]

\matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}]
{
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    &     \\
  & 10 &    & 30 & 4  &        & 50 & 8  &        &    & 12 &    &    &     \\
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    & 125 \\
  &    &    & 10 &    &        & 30 &    &        &    &    &    &    &     \\
  & 4  &    & 40 & -4 &        &    & -4 &        & 35 & 10 &    &    &     \\
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    & 55  \\
  &    &    & 10 &    &        &    &    &        & 5  &    &    &    &     \\
  & 6  &    &    & 4  &        &    & 8  &        &    & -8 &    & 20 &     \\
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    & 30  \\
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    &     \\
  &    & 90 &    &    & \le 60 &    &    & \le 65 &    &    & 20 &    &     \\
};


\draw (m-2-2.north west) rectangle (m-10-13.south east);

% Lineas horizontales
\draw (m-4-2.south west) -- (m-4-13.south east);
\draw (m-7-2.south west) -- (m-7-13.south east);

% Lineas verticales
\draw (m-2-4.north east) -- (m-10-4.south east);
\draw (m-2-7.north east) -- (m-10-7.south east);
\draw (m-2-10.north east) -- (m-10-10.south east);


\draw (m-4-4.north west) rectangle (m-4-4.south east);

\draw (m-2-4.south west) -- (m-2-4.south east);
\draw (m-2-3.north east) -- (m-2-3.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-3-4.south west) -- (m-3-4.south east);
\draw (m-4-3.north east) -- (m-4-3.south east);

%limite superior
\draw (m-2-7.south west) -- (m-2-7.south east);
\draw (m-2-6.north east) -- (m-2-6.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-3-7.south west) -- (m-3-7.south east);
\draw (m-4-6.north east) -- (m-4-6.south east);

% Segunda fila
% Casilla 2-1
%limite superior
\draw (m-5-4.south west) -- (m-5-4.south east);
\draw (m-5-3.north east) -- (m-5-3.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-6-4.south west) -- (m-6-4.south east);
\draw (m-7-3.north east) -- (m-7-3.south east);

% Casilla 2-3
%limite superior
\draw (m-5-10.south west) -- (m-5-10.south east);
\draw (m-5-9.north east) -- (m-5-9.south east);
%limite inferior
\draw (m-6-10.south west) -- (m-6-10.south east);
\draw (m-7-9.north east) -- (m-7-9.south east);

% Tercera fila
% Casilla 3-4
%limite superior
\draw (m-8-13.south west) -- (m-8-13.south east);
\draw (m-8-12.north east) -- (m-8-12.south east);


% Para dibujar cuadrados
%\node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(m-2-2)(m-4-4),inner sep = -5pt] {};

%\node[label=above right:$20$] at (m-2-3){33};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update

Some improvements:

- a helper option "show coordinate" to print coordinate of current cell relative to the matrix (this slows down the compilation and speed up the following drawing), and
- some `\foreach` loop to make line drawing more compact.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\tikzset{
  show coordinate/.style={
    execute option at begin maybe cell={
      label={[red, font=\tiny]center:(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)}
    }
  },
  execute option at begin maybe cell/.style={
    execute at begin cell={|[#1]|},
    execute at empty cell={\node[#1] {};}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.8\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%row 1/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
%column 4/.style={nodes={fill=pink}},
%row 4 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=blue}}
]

\matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}, show coordinate]
{
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    &     \\
  & 10 &    & 30 & 4  &        & 50 & 8  &        &    & 12 &    &    &     \\
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    & 125 \\
  &    &    & 10 &    &        & 30 &    &        &    &    &    &    &     \\
  & 4  &    & 40 & -4 &        &    & -4 &        & 35 & 10 &    &    &     \\
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    & 55  \\
  &    &    & 10 &    &        &    &    &        & 5  &    &    &    &     \\
  & 6  &    &    & 4  &        &    & 8  &        &    & -8 &    & 20 &     \\
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    & 30  \\
  &    &    &    &    &        &    &    &        &    &    &    &    &     \\
  &    & 90 &    &    & \le 60 &    &    & \le 65 &    &    & 20 &    &     \\
};

% Lineas horizontales
\foreach \i in {1,4,7,10} {
  \draw (m-\i-2.south west) -- (m-\i-14.south west);
}

% Lineas verticales
\foreach \j in {1,4,7,10,13} {
  \draw (m-2-\j.north east) -- (m-11-\j.north east);
}

\foreach \k in {2-4, 2-7, 4-4, 4-7, 5-4, 5-10, 7-4, 7-10, 8-13} {
  \draw (m-\k.south west) rectangle (m-\k.north east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! These where just the changes I needed!

Comment: @JohanWideberg Hi I have appended an improved example to my answer. Hope that helps you.

Comment: thats a great option!