# I want to create 10x10 squares and fill the elements all around with zeros?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, overleaf

I want to create 10x10 squares and fill the elements all around with zeros

As shown in the attached images

[image] [image] [image]

But when I add zeros, a space appears between these elements.

Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds}



\newcommand{\0}{\scalebox{2}{$0$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
  \matrix (space) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes={draw, semithick, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=10mm, text=blue}]
{\0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0  & \0 & \0  \\ 
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\ 
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \  & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0  & \0  & \0 & \0  & \0  & \0  \\};




\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
  \matrix (space) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes={draw, semithick, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=10mm, text=blue}]
{\ & \ & \ & \ & \ & \ & \ & \  & \ & \  \\ 
 \ &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \  \\ 
 \ &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \  & \ & \  & \  & \  \\
 \ &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \  \\
 \ &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \  \\
 \ &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \  \\
 \ &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \  \\
 \ &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \  \\
 \ &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \  \\
 \ & \ & \ & \ & \  & \  & \ & \  & \  & \  \\};




\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Giving `font=\vphantom{\0}` to the `nodes` helps correct the vertical alignment and spacing.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers

Comment: `matrix of nodes` sets anchor to `base`, change it to `center`: `nodes={..., anchor=center}`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78964/1952

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (you can change color and/or line width):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[gray!25,line width=.4pt] (0,0) grid (10,10);
 \foreach \x in {.5,1.5,...,9.5}{%
    \node at (\x,.5) () {\tiny 0};
    \node at (\x,9.5) () {\tiny 0};
    \node at (.5,\x) () {\tiny 0};
    \node at (9.5,\x) () {\tiny 0};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

**EDIT**:
If you want black lines, more bigger '0' and want to write the '0' in the four corners one time only (whith some other little cosmetics) this code is better:

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=.4pt] (0,0) grid (10,10);
        \foreach \x in {.5,1.5,...,9.5}{%
            \node[blue] at (\x,.5) () {\bfseries \small 0};
            \node[blue] at (\x,9.5) () {\bfseries \small 0};
        };
        \foreach \x in {1.5,...,8.5}{%
            \node[blue] at (.5,\x) () {\bfseries \small 0};
            \node[blue] at (9.5,\x) () {\bfseries \small 0};
        }
    \draw[red,line width=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
    \draw[red,line width=2pt] (1,1) rectangle (9,9);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The new output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Other than `anchor=center` as Ignasi said in their comments, you can set `text height` and `text depth`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds}

\newcommand{\0}{\scalebox{2}{$0$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
  \matrix (space) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes={draw, semithick, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=10mm, text height=7mm,
    text depth=3mm,
    inner sep=0pt,
    text=blue}]
{\0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0  & \0 & \0  \\ 
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\ 
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \  & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 &\  & \ & \ & \  &  \ & \ & \  & \  & \0  \\
 \0 & \0 & \0 & \0 & \0  & \0  & \0 & \0  & \0  & \0  \\};
\draw[red, very thick] (space-1-1.north west) rectangle (space-10-10.south east);
\draw[red, very thick] (space-2-2.north west) rectangle (space-9-9.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]