# Alignment of nodes of a matrix in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code in latex.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix , arrows.meta , calc}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,    nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1.2cm,draw, outer sep=0pt}] {
%
|[draw](a)| Apple & & |[fill = yellow]|&|[fill = yellow]| & |[fill = yellow]|& |[fill = yellow]|& & & & & & & & & & & \\
%
|[draw](b)| B & & & &|[fill = green]| &|[fill = green]| &|[fill = green]| &|[fill = green]| & & & & & & & & & \\
%
|[draw](c)| C & & & & & &|[fill = blue]| & |[fill = blue]|& |[fill = blue]|& |[fill = blue]|& & & & & & & \\
%
|[draw](d)| D & & & & & & &|[fill = red]| & |[fill = red]|& |[fill = red]|& |[fill = red]|& & & & & & \\
%
|[draw](e)| E & & & & & & & &|[fill = purple]| &|[fill = purple]| &|[fill = purple]| &|[fill = purple]| & & & & & \\
|[draw](f)| F & & & & & & & & |[fill = orange]|& |[fill = orange]| & |[fill = orange]|& |[fill = orange]|& |[fill = orange]|& & & & \\
|[draw](g)| G & & & & & & & & & & & & & |[fill = pink]|& |[fill = pink]|& |[fill = pink]|& |[fill = pink]|\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

I don't understand why the nodes with the text "Apple","B", "C" etc are not aligned horizontally with the other rows of the matrix. Is it because the size of these nodes are bigger? How do I get it to align perfectly with the other nodes?

Comment: A `matrix of nodes` fixes node's anchor to `base`. This way, empty nodes are missaligned with respect to nodes with text. You can add `anchor=center` into `nodes` options and will solve the problem.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78964/1952

Comment: Another workaround would be to add `nodes={execute at begin node={\strut}}`.